# Magento 1.9.1.0 soap login failed - no error log, no ideas

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, soap

I wrote a script for a soap request in Magento. The script runs perfectly in my local installation and on a small test server. It updates and creates the product data from an external database.

I know now no longer know where to look for the error still.

I always get the following error when you run the script:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Internal Server Error in C:\xampp\htdocs\mage.update.products.v3.php:52
```

A search in the error logs found nothing - because there is no error is listed.

I've tried the following:

- set `default_socket_timeout = 120` in php.ini,
- install ApiImprovements from MageGyver to fix a possible header issue

Did any of you a piece of advice? Even now, many, many thanks!

**Edit**

Now I see following errors in the logfile:

```
[Thu Jun 18 16:10:58.121061 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1940] [client <ip>:59643] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  SoapServer::SoapServer(https://<magehost>/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /var/www/vhosts/<magehost>/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Soap/Server.php on line 814
[Thu Jun 18 16:10:58.121095 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1940] [client <ip>:59643] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  SoapServer::SoapServer(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;https://<magehost>/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1&quot; in /var/www/vhosts/<magehost>/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Soap/Server.php on line 814
[Thu Jun 18 16:10:58.121112 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1940] [client <ip>:59643] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://<magehost>/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity "https://<magehost>/index.php/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1"
[Thu Jun 18 16:10:58.121124 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1940] [client <ip>:59643] mod_fcgid: stderr:  in /var/www/vhosts/<magehost>/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Soap/Server.php on line 814
```

Comment: Clearly states the issue is server-side. You might want to check the access logs.

Comment: Hi @Thomas! Found a from FastCGI last night. But to set up timeouts only partially solves the problem. Finally, it may not be the appropriate to modify global settings only for the SOAP request, right?

Comment: Bump! Did you solve this in the end @SFrey ?